# Java base class and sub class methods override

Tags: java, base-class

I am new to Java programming, but have some basic understanding. Here is my question,
i have a base class and many classes extends this base class. In some cases, after a  standard 
action performed by the base class method , i need to do some action only for some sub classes.
So i just done as in the following way. Just want to check i am right as per OOPS

```
class BaseClass {

    public void deleteThisRecord() {
        // All standard code goes here
        doSomethingAfterDelete(); // call clean up method after sucessful delete
    }   

    public void doSomethingAfterDelete() {
        // Nothing is here, let the sub class override this if there is need
    }
}

class OneClass extends BaseClass {
    // other methods

    @Override
    public void doSomethingAfterDelete() {
        // do some action after delete
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work if the base class has a default implementation, and you want some subclasses to change. If you want the sub class to be forced to have it you may want to think about using abstract classes

Comment: This question is more on-topic for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ but to give you my opinion there is nothing illegal about doing this. I do it sometimes since it is slightly more flexible than abstract methods. Sometimes I only want _some_ of the subclasses to do something.

Comment: You probably should make `deleteThisRecord()` **final** so the subclass do not implement it again without the call to `doSomethingAfterDelete()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this will work in the way that you describe, in that derived classes can choose to implement `doSomethingAfterDelete()` or not. However, in Java, all methods of a base class can be overridden by default in the derived class, so you may like to add the `final` modifier to your method `deleteThisRecord()` to prevent it being overridden:

```
public final void deleteThisRecord() {
    // All standard code goes here
    doSomethingAfterDelete(); // call clean up method after successful delete
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Abstract methods are placeholder methods that can only be called from the subclass.  I suggest that if doSomethingAfterDelete() is an empty placeholder method intended to be overridden, you should write it as:

```
public abstract void doSomethingAfterDelete();
```

and then in the subclass, override it.

Comment: The base class would also have to be declared abstract as well.